# How to fill a field in a form with a query, based on data in the form in MS 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm new to access. I have 2 tables, Artists and Paintings, and have made a form from Paintings (displaying all of the fields in that table). It has a reference to the primary key (id) of the Artist table. I have added another text box to the paintings form, and want to display the artist name, based on the id I already have. How can I get this data displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combobox wizard to add a combo box based on the artists table with a control source set to the ArtistID.

It will have properties on these lines:

```
Control Source : ArtistID
Row Source: SELECT ID, ArtistName FROM Artists
Bound Column: 1
Column Count : 2
Column Widths: 0cm;2cm
```